# Issue with SQL Update ussing PHP session variable

Tags: php, sql

I've made a web page where you can register and log in, and once you log in you can edit your profile and also upload an avatar. I'm working on the avatar part right now and I can't figure out why it doesn't work. I will show you some parts of my code so hopefully you can help me.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
         $avatar_path = $mysqli->escape_string('images/'.$_FILES['avatar']['name']);

         if (preg_match("!image!",$_FILES['avatar']['type'])) {

            if (copy($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $avatar_path)) {
```

//It copies the image to the specified path so i know it works till here.

```
                $_SESSION['avatar'] = $avatar_path;
```

And here is the problem, because it basically does nothing, it doesn't even return an error message so I don't know what's wrong with my SQL. 
(`$_SESSION[msg1]` is equal to your username (I know it because I printed it here), so basically what I'm trying to do is insert the avatar path into the users table where username is equal to your username, but it does nothing.

```
                $sql = "UPDATE users SET avatar = $avatar_path WHERE username = $_SESSION[msg1]";

                if ($mysqli->query($sql) === true){
                    header("Location: index.php");
                }
            }
         }         
    }
```

Comment: You don't know what's wrong because you don't check for errors in your code. Never assume the code is always going to work flawlessly. Use [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get a detailed error message from the database.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt know i can do that because im now to all this sql and php stuff, i did what you said and it returns me this error: printf("Errormessage:Unknown column 'amurin' in 'where clause' (amurin is the session variable)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Formate your query like so:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET avatar = '" . $avatar_path . "' WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['msg1'] . "'";

if ($mysqli->query($sql) === true){
    header("Location: index.php");
}
else
{
    die("Database Query Failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote or mark as correct answer ;)